# getting telegram channel posted photos with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I want when a specific channel post a photo my bot download that photo
bot is a member of channel

here is my code :

```
if update.channel_post.photo:
    bot.get_file(file_id=update.channel_post.photo.file_id).download()
```

Actual behaviour : 
the if condition never become true even when channel post a photo

Version of Python, python-telegram-bot & dependencies:
latest versions of all

Comment: Does bot have channel admin rights?

Comment: @Sean yes bot have admin rights

Comment: It's strange :(    Can you post more code?

Comment: @Sean this is all of code i write till now. in case of text it works fine but with photo it don't

Comment: And where is `update` comes from? :D

Comment: @Sean bot is admin of a channel and update is the channel's post

Comment: I mean did you defined `update` previous?

Comment: @Sean yes of course . here is all documentation of python-telegram-bot: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/telegram

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you because you don't have enough code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason your code doesn't work is that it has an error. `Message.photo` is actually a list of different photo sizes, so
`file_id=update.channel_post.photo.file_id` should be `file_id=update.channel_post.photo[-1].file_id` (to get the biggest size)

I also recommend you enable logging, so you will see errors like this more easily.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```